# Why don't we redistribute inversely in this implementation of Radix sort of strings

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I found this implementation of radix sort LSD for strings :

```
public static void sort(String[] input, int w) {
    String[] aux = new String[input.length];
    //ascii chars
    int R = 256;
    int n = input.length;
    
    for(int d = w-1; d >= 0; d--) {
        
        int[] count = new int[R+1];
        //update the frequency at i+1 index
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            count[input[i].charAt(d) + 1] ++;
        }
        
        //transform the frequency into indices
        for(int r=0; r< R; r++) {
            count[r+1] += count[r];
        }
        
        //redistribute
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            aux[count[input[i].charAt(d)]++] = input[i];
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            input[i] = aux[i];
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't understand two things :

1. why here we have `count[input[i].charAt(d) + 1] ++;` rather than `count[input[i].charAt(d)] ++;` ?
2. why we don't redistribute the characters inversely ? I think it's way simpler (my implementation) :

   ```
    public static void sort(String[] arr, int lenStr) {
    int R = 256;
    int len = arr.length;
    String[] arrSorted = new String[len];

    for (int d = lenStr - 1; d >= 0; d--) {
        // frequency count of each character
        int[] count = new int[R + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            count[arr[i].charAt(d)]++;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < count.length; i++) {
            count[i] += count[i - 1];
        }
        for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            count[arr[i].charAt(d)]--;
            arrSorted[count[arr[i].charAt(d)]] = arr[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            arr[i] = arrSorted[i];
        }
    }
   ```

   }

Comment: Write some tests and compare the output of both implementations. If both pass your tests and create the same output, take which one you like more. If one fails a test or outputs differ, start debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I think most of it comes down to personal preference.

> why here we have count[input[i].charAt(d) + 1] ++; rather than count[input[i].charAt(d)] ++; ?

Their `count[x+1]` means, after the second inner loop, `how many times character x and any character prior to it appear`. For example, we might have the initial counts:

```
count[0] = 0
count[1] = 2
count[2] = 3
```

Then after the second for loop we will have:

```
count[0] = 0
count[1] = 2
count[2] = 5
```

This means that character 0 takes the positions between `count[0]` and `count[1]`, character 1 takes the positions between `count[1]` and `count[2]` and in general, character x takes the positions between `count[x]` and `count[x+1]` This allows them to do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    aux[count[input[i].charAt(d)]++] = input[i];
}
```

Which is a nice one liner that ties everything together neatly IMO, because `count[x]` changes to mean `at what position should we next place character x in our sorted array`.

Your implementation works just as well and can also be turned into a one liner:

```
 for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     arrSorted[--count[arr[i].charAt(d)]] = arr[i];
 }
```

If you think it's simpler then you can use it, I don't see any downsides (assuming you've tested it well enough). It's a pretty complex algorithm and once you understand one way of doing it, you tend to stick with it. This is just the implementation that stuck I guess. Simplicity is highly subjective here, personally I think your version is just as complex.